# Efficiency of different methods of calling jQuery document ready 

Tags: jquery

Just curious...

I begin my jquery code with this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { /*code here*/ })
```

Whenever my co-worker worked on the js file I created he would always changed it to this

```
(function($) { /*code here*/ })(jQuery);
```

I do not like using the shorthand version for readability purposes(my preference) and as far as I know there is no difference. But if there's a difference...I'd definitely be using the shorthand.

I don't know if it's normal to be frustrated with someone from your team that changed your code and you don't get an explanation why...so I ask here...to clarify.

Is this just personal preference?

Comment: i agree with you , atleast first one tells that you are doing something with jquery , the second one looks so generic that new people may get confused , yeah i always prefer document.ready is it self says its getting ready or so ///somewhat readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no difference in performance between the shorthand notation and writing it all out.  Just a matter of preference.

As far as getting frustrated with someone on your team... if you're working on a team, you -really- need to document some coding standards.  You'll need to make some concessions as well as the other team member(s) in order to arrive at a standard that everybody will agree upon.

With no standard, everybody's free to do as they choose... and spending time re-writing working code to suit a style preference isn't exactly productive.  If there were coding standards defined, that behavior would be reduced (one would hope).

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

If you're making jQuery plugins, or using jQuery for specific use cases, following the plugin pattern seems to be the most preferred method by the community.

however,

```
(function($){
    $(function(){
        // do stuff on doc ready
    });
})(jQuery);
```

or

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // do stuff on doc ready
    });
})(jQuery);
```

is the equivalent to your

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    // do stuff on doc ready
});
```

your coworker's code will execute immediately when loaded, so please educate them.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: woops, didn't read the question properly, ammended answer below.

**The two do different things...**

In the first, the code runs once the document is ready and elements can be accessed, while the second one runs immediately. Therefore if the code is in the `<head>` section of the page and accesses elements, **the second won't function properly**. However, if it doesn't depend on the page being loaded, then the second is more correct.

Comment: I always put scripts after the html footer. I've read on it somewhere, the scripts should be at the bottom of the page, while css on top as better practice. If you don't mind me asking...which do you prefer using in your web dev projects. Thanks...

Comment: The second one done properly:

(function($){$(function() {
  // on doc ready, do stuff
});})(jQuery);

Comment: @Woppi - Personal opinion only: Putting `<script>` at end of html is counter-intuitive and should be used only if performance is really an issue. If the site is script-heavy, dynamic script loading (and consequently, better structuring of "base" and "optional" JS) is preferable anyway. I could be wrong on this, interested to hear others' opinions.

Comment: @tester - kind of verbose, no? The anonymous function doesn't really do anything in that situation.

Comment: @Box9 Found the link, read up on it a long time ago. Just sharing http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: @box9, perhaps, but it allows you to be flexible with your scopes if your docready method has a lot going on. within the wrapping anonymous function I could write _privateMethod()'s then utilize them to reduce complexity in my doc ready statement instead of doing everything inside of doc ready. Again, it's just personal preference, but if readability is key, simplifying what goes on in docready is necessary.

Comment: @tester Agreed about the flexibility. I somehow assumed that whatever code was being used in the poster's question was meant to be executed only on page load.

Comment: @box9 You're right...only on page load...like for example, only after login page was loaded that a login.js will be included and some md5 js plugin. Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 1):

Your chosen syntax is more readable to someone who isn't familiar with jQuery.

Comment: Read the question again... I thought the same, but realised the "shorthand" isn't actually the shorthand.